# How to run external program via a C# program?

Tags: c#

How do I run an external program like Notepad or Calculator via a C# program?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think it's safe to assume that English is your second language.
To increase your chances of getting an answer, I would re-write the question title to say "How to open an external program from a C# program?". Also is it a Console App, Winforms, Web(hopefully not)? Provide a little more information, and make sure you check out the Stack Overflow FAQ.

Comment: @Michael I assume hw is simply how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start a process from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Answer (score 63):

Maybe it'll help you:

```
using(System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Vitor\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
    pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "olaa"; //argument
    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //not diplay a windows
    pProcess.Start();
    string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
    pProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Remember to dispose the process or use it in a `using(Process pProcess = new Process()) { }` block

Answer (score 32):

Use [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Comment: FYI "Example" is a dead link. Always the drawback when specifying links.

Comment: Maybe it is just my failing eyesight then

Comment: Not dead in the sense that it doesnt lead anywhere, dead in the sense that it doesnt actually show an example.

Answer (score 15):

Hi this is Sample Console Application to Invoke Notepad.exe ,please check with this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process ExternalProcess = new Process();
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            ExternalProcess.Start();
            ExternalProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For example like this :

```
// run notepad
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");

//run calculator
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe");
```

Follow the links in Mitchs answer.