# How to make a program install ANOTHER program with c#

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to create a program that when a button is pressed, it goes into my FTP server and auto installs another program into the client's computer.

The program is deleting the old file on the client's computer. And installing in the new one.

```
    if (!new WebClient().DownloadString("ftp://username:password@asdf.bplaced.net/version.txt").Contains("1.0.0.0"))

                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (MessageBox.Show("New Update! Would you like to update?", "Yay!",
                                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) ==
                                System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
Process.Start("ftp://username:password@asdf.bplaced.net/place/thing.exe");
                                Application.Exit();
                                ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                                Info.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del " +
                                               Application.ExecutablePath;
                                Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                                Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                                Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                                Process.Start(Info);
```

> Process.Start("ftp://username:password@asdf.bplaced.net/place/thing.exe");

This is the new file that I want installed into the client's computer. So far it leads the client to a web browser which opens a browser at a download link. I want it to auto install into their computer.

Comment: download the file and then call process.start

Comment: @Steve Sorry, but what do you mean by download??? I am trying to make the client download the file THROUGH the process.start.

Comment: Why you call `Application.Exit` before you create and start the process?

Comment: download the thing.exe using DownloadFile method or something.And then process.start("thing.exe")

Comment: These are two separate tasks (download and run/install). Ask them separately.

Comment: I need it to go through the FTP server without opening their browser.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is a file copy protocol, and it is not a remote file system. Consequently you wont get windows to execute a file hosted on an FTP server. You should download the file using the FTP protocol to a local Temp folder, then execute the file you downloaded.

Comment: Can you point me into a post that says how to do that? I can't find one.

Comment: Really ? Searching for ".net ftp client download file" didn't pull up hundreds of hits like this one ? http://www.schiffhauer.com/downloading-a-file-from-ftp-with-system-net-ftpclient/ And searching ".net execute external program" didn't give you a zillion hits much like this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173775/how-to-run-external-program-via-a-c-sharp-program You need to hone your googling skills a little my friend.