# Running another piece of software using C# program?

Tags: c#, operating-system

Is it do-able to write a C# program that will open up another piece of software, and make it do something? For example, could I open up Audacity and play a tone using a C# program? I'm looking to automate a couple of tasks, and this would be necessary.

Sorry I don't have any code, but I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Use [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes it is. If Audacity has APIs to interact with it then that is great, otherwise you have to use automation tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run external program via a C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173775/how-to-run-external-program-via-a-c-sharp-program)

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start("Location Of File.exe");

(Make sure you use the System.Diagnostics library)