# how can run this cmd command "bcdedit /set testsigning on" by c#?

Tags: c#, process, console, cmd

how can run this cmd command "bcdedit /set testsigning on" by c#?
this my code - no run :

```
        string strCmdLine;
        strCmdLine = "bcdedit /set testsigning on";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a process from C# (WinForms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c-winforms)

Comment: I do not use bat file, I want to use with cmd.exe

Comment: What did that thread have to do with bat-files? Anyway, all you need to know is written in the thread mentioned above. Just set `FileName` to the path to cmd, and arguments to `-C <command>` (if my memory serves me right).

Comment: can you give me an example of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing some details on the actual issue here...

Here's my guess, I think you are missing the **/c** flag.

```
 string strCmdLine;
 strCmdLine = "/c bcdedit /set testsigning on";
 Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
```

See the help of cmd.exe for more details on the **/c** flag (cmd /?).

Comment: Thank you
This is exactly the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "bcdedit /set testsigning on" );

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, just replace "format" with "bcdedit", and "/? with "/set testsigning on"

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("format", "/?");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
string output = Process.Start(info).StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

You don't need the last 2 lines if you do not care about the output, you should also consider redirecting error output and forwarding it to the console as well (in case you get any error