# Starting another application from within C# code

Tags: c#, process, environment-variables

How can I start another application from within C# code? I can't get this piece to work correctly

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Application\chrome.exe");
```

Edit:
Wow I was dumb and just noticed what I forgot in the filepath. Thanks for the answers though they helped teach me some other useful things.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: You could also just get the value of the env var from the `Environment` class.

Comment: It won't work if Chrome isn't installed, or isn't installed in that path.

Comment: That's principally correct, though I'm not sure whether Process.Start resolves %userprofile% or not.  Also, by default, Chrome.exe is not installed in the path you indicate.

Comment: @EricJ.My Chrome is installed there.

Comment: @leppie: Not on my system.  Could be part of the problem...

Comment: @EricJ. I have the dev version of Chrome installed and it automatically went there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think `Process.Start` expands environment variables for you. Try this:

```
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Application\chrome.exe");
Process.Start(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/start_an_external_app.aspx) for starting external program
Also try this  [Similar Question on stackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c-sharp-winforms)

this is an example here

```
 string winpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
              System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);

 Process.Start(winpath + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\Installutil.exe",
 path + "\\MyService.exe");
```

And in your case ,write the following on top where all the **using namespaces**  are listed

```
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System;
```

so then in your code directly write the above code...