# How to run another installed program in C# code

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start a process from C# (WinForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c-sharp-winforms)

I developed a speech recognition application. Now, all I want to do is something like

```
if(voiceRecognize == browser)
   //Open a browser
```

I think you understand what I mean. I know it is possible but how can I perform this task??

Any sample code or tutorial link will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Many duplicates of this! A search would probably have saved you time :)

Comment: Thanks :-) I flagged it as duplicate. Hope moderator will delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You may be able to launch an actual webpage kinda like this:

```
Process.Start("\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\" /\"http://www.google.com\"");
```

Comment: or just `Process.Start("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: Yeah, don't hard-code to IE :(

Comment: I assume that would launch it in the default browser... cool. Didn't realize Process.Start() was that smart :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard: It's just an example. But I totally get your point.

Comment: @jwatts1980, yup you can also pass it any file and it will open it with the default handler - .txt, .doc, .jpg, etc

Comment: If you wanna get tricky you can also lookup their `http` key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT