# sending command to cmd through c#

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I want to *execute a command* to lock the drive through bit locker when button is clicked. How to do this? I'm new in c#

The command is:

```
manage-bde -lock x:
```

How it will be send to console? here is the code

```
private void btnlock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C manage-bde -lock "+textBox1.Text+":";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a process from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c)

Comment: but the other links are not helping ,comaand didn't get executed

Comment: i added my code which show no response(not working),textbox1 has the name of drive which i want to lock

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Process` class in `System.Diagnostics` namespace.
It should be something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("manage-bde", "-lock x:");
```

Comment: can u elaborate more please

Comment: replace x with the drive letter, or in your case, replace it with textBox1.Text

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("manage-bde", "-lock "+textBox1.Text+":");

Comment: i did but it throws exception,*The system cannot find the file specified*

Comment: Have you tried to specify full path to `manage-bde` executable?

Comment: it need administrative privileges to execute,how to give it?

Answer (score 0):

The command isn't being executed because your command line doesn't know where to find the `manage-bde` program.

All you need to do is add the full path of the file like so:

`startInfo.Arguments = @"/C C:\Program Files\Foo\manage-bde.exe -lock "+textBox1.Text+":";`

Note: I'm not sure if the `.exe` part is necessary, but it doesn't hurt adding it in. Also, make sure you either use 2 backslashes (`\\`) or use the `@` before the quotation mark at the start.