# Unzipping without external package in .net 4.0 with Shell command?

Tags: c#

I was wondering whether it is possible to unzip files in c sharp without using open source dll's in .net 4.0 or lower?

I have some VBA code (below) that uses the "Shell" command. Is that also possible from c sharp?

```
Sub UnzipMe(path)

Dim strDOSCMD As String
Dim filename As String
Dim i As Integer


filename = path + "\test.txt"
strDOSCMD = "unzip -n " + path + "\zipfile.zip -d " + path
'SEND TO DOS
retval = Shell(strDOSCMD, vbHide)


End Sub
```

This works fine and is very simple but I would like to do it all in c sharp and not mix and match. Surely that should be doable or there should be an equally simple solution?

Comment: You can use 'Process.Start' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c to launch your DOS command, but consider to use a third party component

Comment: thanks. What third party package do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a process in C# using [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Your code can look like (not tested..):

```
public void UnzipMe(string path){
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C unzip -n " + path + "\zipfile.zip -d " + path;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    //do some extra stuff here
}
```

For zip stuff consider to use a third party library like [`sharpziplib`](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) I use it with success in many projects.

Take a look to these samples: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples

Comment: thanks Edward. I have breifly looked at sharpziplib, do you mind posting a simply unzip function based on that package please?

Comment: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#wiki-anchorUnpackFull