# System.FileNotFound exception

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, process.start, mmc

So I am trying to automatically launch mmc compmgmt.msc with the only switch it seems to have (/computer:\). It works just fine from a local run box, but not by utilizing Process.Start. Here is the offending line:

```
Process.Start("mmc c:\\windows\\system32\\compmgmt.msc /computer:\\\\" + computerNameTextBox.Text.ToString());
```

Any ideas? I've tried using @ as well, with the same results, so it doesn't seem to be an escape character issue...it's something else...

PLEASE NOTE: stack overflow modified the escape characters in the above text string. They are properly there

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: The title lists the error I am getting, sorry about that

Comment: Not on point, but isn't `computerNameTextBox.Text.ToString()` redundant?  Could be just `computerNameTextBox.Text`, right?

Comment: Have you not found any of the provided answers helpful? If you have, you should mark it as accepted. Otherwise, do tell us what's wrong, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command and arguments must be passed as separate parameters. Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I facepalmed so hard ha ha ha. Thank you, my good sir. When SO allows it, I will accept this as an answer. Been grinding this code for a good solid 36 hours, kinda getting tunnel vision.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use separate parameters, this will not work at all. **Process.Start** has an overload to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `Process.Start()` method incorrectly. It should look like this

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("mmc");
startInfo.Arguments = "c:\\windows\\system32\\compmgmt.msc /computer:\\\\" 
                       + computerNameTextBox.Text.ToString();
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

For more information, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c) SO question.