# open .msg file using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, outlook, process.start

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process first = new Process();   
startInfo.FileName = "OUTLOOK";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "http:\\blabla.com\EMAIL.msg";
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;                        
                    first.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    first.Start();
```

i used Process.Start to start up Outlook and open a .Msg file. how can i reuse the same process to open another .msg file without opening multiple processes/threads/instances of outlook?

i have tried something like

```
Process[] outlook = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");
Process existing = outlook[0];
                    startInfo.FileName = "outlook";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "http:\\blabla.com\2ndEMAIL.msg";
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    existing.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    existing.Start();
```

to reuse the same process but i'm still opening multiple windows of outlook instead of just the .MSG file it

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified your code, this might work.

```
var first = new Process();
var pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "http:\\blabla.com\EMAIL.msg",
                Arguments = "/quiet",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
first.StartInfo = pinfo;
first.Start();
```

Comment: @user1166085 Will you help me understanding what cases solution not handled, will try to improve it (if possible).

Comment: you can try re-using the process (first) that you created and try to open another .msg file. it will open up another outlook. i'm looking for way(s) to avoid opening up another outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Only one instance of Outlook can be run at the same time.

> how can i reuse the same process to open another .msg file without opening multiple processes/threads/instances of outlook?

You can use the Process.Start method to open the message in Outlook. There is no need to specify Outlook, only path to the .msg file.

Be aware, the Application class in Outlook provides you the [CreateItemFromTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865637.aspx) method. It creates a new Outlook item based on the specified template and returns the newly created Outlook item. You can use it to create an Outlook item based on the .MSG file. See [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) for more information.

Comment: yeah the scenario here is that whenever i try to open an .msg file, it opens up another outlook 'window'. was wondering if there's a way to only open the .msg file and not an outlook window. does the CreateItemFromTemplate fit into my scenario here?

Comment: i'm thinking that it wouldn't fit as i'm just trying to open a .msg file and not storing it. i need a solution that allows me to open a .msg file without opening additional outlook windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the already open Outlook messages, it is your responsibility to do so - use Application.Inspectors collection to enumerate all messages that Outlook is currently displaying and close them.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
var process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = fullPath //path of msg file
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: How would that help? Outlook is a singleton, each time your open an MSG file, the control is transferred to the already running instance of Outlook, which will open another inspector window. There will be still just one instance of outlook.exe running.