# How Can Manage any other exe with another win form

Tags: c#

I have a solution with two projects:

- Windows forms application
- Console application.

I want to manage the console application from the windows form application.

How cant i start/stop the console application from the windows forms applciation?

can any one provide a sample code or any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `Process.Start`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "yourexe.exe";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

For further information take a look at [this StackOverflow link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c)

Comment: this is declared in windows from?

Comment: @user3671253 What do you mean? Simply use the code from where you want to start your console application.