# how to start a process under Windows with call?

Tags: c#, windows

I have the following code which works under Linux :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 

// Set in the process the executable and arguments
startInfo.FileName = "ps";
startInfo.Arguments = "a";

Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

proc.WaitForExit();

return proc.ExitCode;
```

However when I try using the process under Windows for a simple commands :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 

// Set in the process the executable and arguments
startInfo.FileName = "call";
startInfo.Arguments = "gpedit.msc";

Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

proc.WaitForExit();

return proc.ExitCode;
```

It doesn't work (I know running thins command in cmd.exe works fine).

I get : `Win32Exception was unhandled`.

I also read this tutorial over again : [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c)

I used process a lot under Linux but I cannot see what I do wrong in Windows.

Comment: Is 'call' in the same directory as the executable of your code?

Comment: `CALL` is a batch command, only available from the command line. You should be able to just specify `gpedit.msc` as the “file name” without specifying any argument to launch the management tool.

Comment: gpedit.msc is the process you are trying to run - so that should be the FileName

Comment: Did you read the exception yet?

Comment: 1-)Call is indeed in the same directory
2-) I'm gonna try not having the call and report if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `CALL` is a batch command, only available from the command line (poke)

I instead use start and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two Options:

Call the MMC executable with `GPEDIT` parameter

```
startInfo.FileName = "MMC.EXE";
startInfo.Arguments = "GPEDIT.MSC";
```

Or call `GPEDIT.MSC` with no parameters

```
startInfo.FileName = "GPEDIT.MSC";
```