# How do i run a program or function when my main program ends in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to windows development and I need that.

In php I can do like that:

```
<?php

exec("second.sh > /dev/null 2>&1")

?>
```

When I do that the php program call the second.sh program to run and exit without waiting the second.sh exit

I need this behavior in c# program

My second program will run for 5 minutes and exit.
I need to make a POST, but I do not want to wait the request to finish to continue the main program, because this request can take 5 min to finish.

Run another program is a 'workaround' I saw on php.
The ideal would be call a HttpWebRequest and do not wait it to finish.

Comment: Look into [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you need a new program? Because what you describe can be solved with simple threading as well.

Answer (score 2):

### The short answer

You can launch another process like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics; // This goes in your usings at the top
...
Process.Start("process.exe");
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c). The program needs to be on your PATH so that you can run it by name like that. Otherwise you'll need to specify its full file path.

### However

You could do all of this in one program if you wanted:

```
public void Main()
{
    //Your main program

    // [Send the POST]

    // Now start another thread to wait for the response while we do other stuff
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(GetResponse));

    //Do other stuff
    //...
}

private void GetResponse(object state)
{
    // Check for evidence of POST response in here
}
```

I don't know how your second program checks for the POST response, but whatever it is, you could replicate that logic in GetResponse.

Comment: I do not want to check the response of the POST. I would like to make a POST and do not wait for it

Answer (score 1):

"The ideal would be call a HttpWebRequest and do not wait it to finish."

You can do TaskFactory.StartNew(() => Something.HttpWebRequest("url"));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone 
I end up with that:

```
System.Threading.ThreadStart th_start = () =>
{
    slowFunction(arg);

};

System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(th_start)
{
    IsBackground = true
};

th.Start();
```

For some reason the  TaskFactory.StartNew did not run my slowFunction:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
   new MyApp().slowFunction(arg), 
   System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
   TaskCreationOptions.None,
   TaskScheduler.Default
);
```