# Printing out Apostrophe through a program

Tags: c#

```
string s1 = "This is";
string s2 = "Overview";

List<string> lines = Files.ReadLines(f).ToList();
If (lines.Count>i)
lines.Insert(i, s1+ s2);

else
lines.Add(s1 + s2);
File.WriteAllLines(f, lines);
```

I am getting an out put of 
This is Overview...
I need an out of 
This is "Overview"..

I tried putting apostrophes directly but it says error.. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "This is";
string s2 = "\"Overview\"";

List<string> lines = Files.ReadLines(f).ToList();
If (lines.Count>i)
lines.Insert(i, s1+ s2);

else
lines.Add(s1 + s2);
File.WriteAllLines(f, lines);
```

Comment: Thanks man.. It works great.. And another thing.. Like.. If i want to put the whole program in loop like after executing it should return to the start of the program and run again..

Comment: please explain with example

Comment: like say i have a simple hello world program triggered by user input.. So that if i run the program and press enter it will show the hello world msg.. And if i want the program to be in continues loop like even after showing the hello world msg, it should return back to "press any key to see the msg" function.. The loop will go on till user press escape...

Comment: dude.   You there bro