# Run DISM /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 in CMD from a Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, frameworks, .net-3.5, dism

I am developing a software where a user clicks a button and enables the Framework feature it is a WINFORM with C# coding.

My Question is how can I from a WINFORM run a command as admin and pass`DISM /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3` for it to run?

I viewed at the other answers in the forum and they don't help.

Comment: `cmd` does not take parameters like that.  You want `/c`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start a process from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)