# Run a command line process from unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exe

I am trying to run an external .exe file with argument from unity, this what I have been doing:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("AAA.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;      
startInfo.Arguments = "MyArgument";         
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But an error keeps telling me that unity couldn't find the executable file.
How can I add a path or make unity find the executable file?
Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you may be giving an incorrect Path to your .exe

Try something like this:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "/YourSubDirectory/yourprogram.exe");

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fullPath);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.Arguments = "MyArgument";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

[Application Paths in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) - Dependent on where your .exe is based, this may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may need to use a path relative to your unity build.exe's folder in order to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You should either specify the full path or a relative path of the executable. 
Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c) for some examples.