# How to execute vsjitdebugger.exe using c#

Tags: c#

I'd like to execute 'vsjitdebugger.exe' for some process using the code below:

```
var myapp = Process.Start(@"path\to\myapp.exe");
Process.Start("vsjitdebugger.exe", $"-p {myapp.Id}").WaitForExit();
```

But failed.
The exit code is '-1' without showing the window.

What do I have to do in order to execute vsjitdebugger.exe?

**UPATE #1**
I'd like to attach debugger to the specific process only instantly.
That's why I profer code way instead of registry way.

To execute as administrator:

```
var myapp = Process.Start(@"path\to\myapp.exe");
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
     FileName = @"vsjitdebugger.exe",
     Arguments = "-p {myapp.Id}",
     Verb = "runas"
}).WaitForExit();
```

Failed as well after UAC screen.

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c

Comment: this is different as he is trying to run the JIT debugger on some process.

Answer (score 0):

Lunching the just-in-time debugger through code will not work for you as you must run with admin privileges in order to use it.

What you can do, is start the debugger [Automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/a329t4ed(v=vs.90)) on your desired process.

I'd suggest reading more about the JIT of visual studio [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger) as well before trying to execute process through C#.

This is not safe at all and considered bad practice. Unless there is an urgent need I would suggest maxing out all your other possibilities first.