# UWP FolderPicker does not grant me permission to access folder

Tags: c#, uwp

The following code is taken from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) on the subject with slight modification:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
    // (including other sub-folder contents)
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
    FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);

    if (Directory.Exists(folder.Path)) // fails, I don't have permission to read this folder even though the documentation suggests that I should have access
    {
        this.textBlock.Text = "Picked folder: " + folder.Name; // never gets printed
    }
}
```

I also tried adding the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to the application manifest. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**broadFileSystemAccess** only works with [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage) namespace, and this is already mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) as follows :

> This is a restricted capability. On first use, the system will prompt
>   the user to allow access. Access is configurable in Settings > Privacy
>
> > File system. If you submit an app to the Store that declares this capability, you will need to supply additional descriptions of why
> >     your app needs this capability, and how it intends to use it. This
> >     capability works for APIs in the Windows.Storage namespace

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way to, say, run a `Process.Start()` on a particular folder when working with `UWP` applications?

Comment: I am not aware of what process.start is, what is your use case here?

Comment: You can use `Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync` to open a folder in file explorer

Comment: @touseefbsb: sorry I was a bit vague. I meant something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/181857/368599 (or something as simple as `Directory.Exists("D:/my_dir");`

Comment: @MartinZikmund: I need to run a process in a particular folder. I have a library that already does that. Problem is when I call the functions of the library (that otherwise work) from a UWP application, I get an access denied exception.

Comment: The thing is you cannot work with classic File IO  classes. You will need to use StorageFolder and StorageFile instead

Comment: I m sure there is a way with Windows.Storage as well to do exactly the same, u may use "storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync(path)" and if check if the folder sucefully returns means it exists.

Comment: @touseefbsb: right, however that was just an example of the functionality I would like to run. I have an (existing) library that runs system commands (which is why I mentioned `Process.Start()`) for various operations, including `git`.

Regardless, it turns out the only way to do that would be to launch a process with the `FullTrustProcessLauncher`. However, that requires a redesign of the existing library.

Answer (score 0):

UWP applications have limited access and the regular IO commands do not work, including `System.Diagnostic.Process`. The only way to launch a process is to use `FullTrustProcessLauncher Class` as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.

Working examples can be found here: https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust

However, this does not solve the problem of working with existing libraries since they are not *processes* in the first place. We now have an RPC service where the requests are made from the service and results obtained.