# How can I run a method in a new thread, in a new command window?

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, command-line-interface

I am trying to implement a piece of software that streams data from machine tools and saves the data it gets back as XML. 
I currently have a GUI driven version which successfully creates a listener with the line 
`Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InitiateEventListener()); // Start the listener`

I am creating a CLI version of this software as it needs to run headless on some machines and would like to be able to have a second window come up at this point to display all of the output driven by this method (the method continues to run until the connection is closed by either communication failure, manual stop, or an end of stream message given by the other device.) 
Unfortunately just running the method on a separate alone thread doesn't help me as my UI does not come back to user input, instead the window focuses on the new thread. 
If I could do this I would be able to launch multiple listeners with different search parameters from my CLI.

Comment: No, I'm very new to c# and not familiar with it. I'll check it out.

Comment: Lol I actually give up on trying to build rep on this SE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to run it in a separate console.  Use "curses" to create a console based UI and separate the two.

This library will allow you to create some console based UI allowing two seperate "windows" for output.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/

Thats what >I< would do.