# Start a process from another project for integration testing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Framework project that requires running a built console application from a .NET Core project in the same solution.

Take the example file structure:

- `Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe`
- `Service/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Service.dll`

The current approach involves [starting a new process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c), similar to the following:

```
dotnet run ../../../Service/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Service.dll
```

I am fairly new to .NET, and so unsure if the following ideas are possible:

- Modifying the path when running the Test application so that I can start the Service process with `dotnet run Service.dll`.
- Getting the Test project to copy the Service build files into the Test build folder.

For bonus points, if/when the Framework project is upgraded to Core, is it possible to start a Core application process by `using` it in another application?

**Edit:**

For clarification, I'm hoping to avoid using that hard-coded relative path to build output folder, since it changes between Framework and Core and different versions of Core.
My hope is to find a built-in variable or functionality to get the build location of another project (even if I need to hard-code the Debug/Release part).

For example (excuse the pseudocode):

```
using Service;
var path = getPathToDebugBuildFolder(Service);
startProcess(Path.Join(path, "Service.dll"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you right click your project in Visual Studio you can define your Pre- and PostBuild Tasks (Build Events).

And yes.. if you are using .NET Core for both applications then you can Add a reference to your class library / console application and use the public types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you suggesting that I copy the built files from the Service project into the Test project in one of those pre/post-build tasks? If so, I'd currently still be stuck with maintaining a relative path to a possibly changing build folder. I'm hoping to find built-in variables/functionality that may be able to reference the build output folder of the other project.