# I'm getting the error "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'process.waitforexit()". How to rectify it?

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'process.waitforexit()"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace cpu_benchmark
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Reghunaath A A\\source\\repos\\cpu benchmark\\resources\\benchmark result\\bench.exe");
            Process.WaitForExit(100000);
            //StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Reghunaath A A\\source\\repos\\cpu benchmark\\resources\\benchmark result\\count.txt");
            textBox1.Text = "hi";

        }
    }
}
```

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Comment: Any time a method doesn't do what you think it should, the first thing you should do is [read the documentyation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_), which is a static method, [`WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.8) is an instance method.

The `Start` method returns an instance of the `Process` class, and it's that instance you need to wait for its exit - so your code should look like this:

```
var process = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Reghunaath A A\\source\\repos\\cpu benchmark\\resources\\benchmark result\\bench.exe");
process.WaitForExit(100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

An *instance* method needs to be accessed from the instance of an object. Assume you instantiate an object of type `O1` like this:

```
O1 myObject = new O1();
```

Then an instance method is called like `myObject.InstanceMethod()`. On the contrary, a *static* method doesn't need an object instance, it's like this `O1.StaticMethod()`.

In your particular case, `Start` is a static method and `WaitForExit` is an instance method. The `Start` method returns an object instance of the `Process` class, and it's that instance you use to call `WaitForExit`, the code would look like this:

```
var process = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Reghunaath A A\\source\\repos\\cpu benchmark\\resources\\benchmark result\\bench.exe");
process.WaitForExit(100000);
```