# Is there way to run "scp" command on a C# form app

Tags: c#, ssh, raspberry-pi, windows-10, scp

I am trying to send video file from windows10 pc to a raspberry pi (using wi-fi). I can do that with a ssh command "scp". Currently i successed with openssh.

Im using CMD command: "scp myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:project/"
(i followed this:https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/scp.md)

[Looks like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaIf6.png)

I tried a code like this and it is not working:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNSnP.png)

But what i want is, i want to use this command in a windows form app, cant figured out how to that, i tried SSH.NET with C# but i never used that before and im not experienced with Visual Studio C# because of that im kinda stuck now and dont know what to do or where to look actually.

SSH.NET code that i tried:[SSH.NET code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExE8U.png)

Comment: You can just run the command from the winforms project. Something along the lines of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c

Comment: Generally, you wouldn't 'run scp' from C#, you would use a nuget package and implement it in code, which gives you much more control over how copying is going (like error handling, progress bars etc).

Comment: Yea actually i wish to do it with implementing it in to code, i tried it with SSH.NET but cant make it work and im really inexperianced on this topic :/