# Is calling System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() truly problematic?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, windows-store, system.diagnostics, desktop-bridge

In the Validation Result that I get when readying my app for submission to the Microsoft Store (which my app "PASSED WITH WARNINGS"), I got this "Fail" under the "Package Sanity Test" section:

[image]

The code which contains such a call is:

```
private void myMapsHelpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://ramblingnotesofageezer.substack.com/p/map-o-matic-overview");
}
```

I am using that code due to the recommendation to do so here. [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Is this truly a problem? If so, what should I use instead of the call to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()?

I find it odd that it is classified as a failed part of the test, yet the overall results are that my app passed (albeit with warnings).

### UPDATE

I checked out the link in the comment from Codexer, where it says, "Starting a utility can often provide a convenient way to obtain information from the operating system, access the registry, or access system capabilities. However, you can use UWP APIs to accomplish these sorts of tasks instead."

If this is the solution, do the UWP APIs have an equivalent to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()?

### UPDATE 2

I followed the steps in the answer, but the solution still doesn't compile, due to an error with this line of code:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

[image]

In fact, even when I comment out the offending line, the project will no longer compile, but doesn't give me any information about how to solve the problem, just this:

[image]

I set the Package Management Format to PackageReference, and installed version 10.0.18362.2005 of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts, but it is complaining about needing a package reference...?!? I tried adding using Windows.System;
and using Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts; but neither is recognized.

The package is installed for the project, as you can see here:

[image]

### UPDATE 3

Regarding the "Must Use Package Reference" err msg, I have three questions revolving around what I see here:

[image]

The verbiage below Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts says I can update versions of this package - should I?

I do not see a Reference to Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts in my project's References, although it has been installed. Do I need to add one - if so, from where?

The context menu on my References affords me the ability to "Migrate packages.config to PackageReference..." should I do that?

Comment: [Read this](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2566#issuecomment-586080985) as it tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I will update my question diesbzg.

Comment: Shannon check out [calling Windows Runtime API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance). The primary issue you're going to have is users that are using Windows 10 S will not be able to launch this process for security reasons and the reason for your warning when trying to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were developing an uwp application, for opening open a web uri, it is recommended to use [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-19041) method instead, this method starts the default browser to open the specified URI.

For example:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
        }
```

**Update:**

As Codexer mentioned, you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) to use uwp api in winform app.

I have created a winform project, its target framework is .Net Framework4.8. For earlier versions of .NET(.NET Core 3.x, .NET 5 Preview 7 (or earlier), or .NET Framework), you could refer to my steps.

1.Click **Tools**->**NuGet Package Manager**-> **Package Manager Settings**-> Change **Default package management format** to **PackageReference**. As follows:

[image]

2.Install the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` package, note that you need to install the appropriate version. Please check the corresponding version below. (Installation details: Right click **Reference**-> **Manage NuGet Packages**->**Browse**->Search **Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts**->**install**)

- 10.0.19041.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 2004, version 20H2
- 10.0.18362.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 1903.
- 10.0.17763.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 1809.
- 10.0.17134.xxxx: Choose this for Windows 10, version 1803.

[image]

3.Run the project

Comment: Thanks, but I get, "error CS0103: The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context" with this code.

Comment: Could you please tell me what project type your project is? Is it a uwp app?

Comment: Its not uwp clearly... There is no `ToolStripMenu` in uwp.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT It is a Winforms app, for which I am using the Bridge solution (Packaging project) to make it Store-ready.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I have updated my answer, you could try it.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT: My version of Windows (10.0.19042) is not in the list. "Microsoft Windows 10 Home" is I guess another name for my version. 10.0.19041 is the version of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts that is found when I search for that in NuGet, though...should I install that?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I suggest you could choose 10.0.18362.xxxx. When I change the version of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts to 18362, it also works.
If it doesn’t work, you could update your computer operation system version to 2004 or 20H2. If you can't find the 10.0.18362.xxxx version of package, please see the picture of my first answer.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT: Please see Update 2

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I have seen your update. As the context menu on your references mentioned, you need to migrate packages.config to PackageReference. Please follow the reference prompt.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT: Ok, that worked - migrating allowed solution to build.