# How do I add DPI-Awareness to my Visual Studio project?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store, desktop-bridge, dpi-aware

In the ValidationResult that I get when readying my app for submission to the Microsoft Store (which my app "PASSED WITH WARNINGS") , I got this "Warning" under the "High-DPI support" section of the report:

[image]

I definitely do not want users to experience incorrect scaling of UI elements, clipped text, or blurry images, so I want to declare my app as DPI-aware in the app manifest. But just where and how?

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process), and the entry apparently should be something like this:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Most particularly (I reckon) this line is the key one:

```
<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
```

...but I don't see just how I should add that (if it a semi-automated process), or which file to add it to. I searched for "<assembly xmlns" but nothing was found.

I don't want to "wing it" and break something, or make matters worse, so I'd like to know just how to add this DPI-awareness to my app. My solution has a Package.appxmanifest file, but it opens as a GUI set of tabs (on none of which I see anything about DPI), and Package.StoreAssociation.xml, but I don't know where in that I should put such a DPI-Awareness declaration (if that's even the appropriate file to which to add it).

### UPDATE

So I now have this:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

...in the app.manifest file of the main project (not the package project), but I still get that same warning.

### UPDATE 2

Based on the comment and references provided by CoCalceDew, I changed my manifest to this:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <!--<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor/dpiAwareness>-->
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor, System</dpiAwareness>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

...but have to wait until my project compiles again (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66804721/is-calling-system-diagnostics-process-start-truly-problematic) for what the problem is) before seeing if it does the trick.

Comment: **1.** Right click on project **2.** Choose *Add> New Item...* **3.** Choose *Application Manifest File Windows Only* which is located under general C# items **4** Uncomment the section related to *dpiAwareness*

Comment: Thanks for another of your always clear and specific answers, Reza.

Comment: Does above comment solve your problem?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: Now, I posted the Update after that comment - I still get the same warning.

Comment: Please refer the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563725/microsoft-store-certification-fails-due-to-dpi-awareness) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537990/wpf-clickonce-dpi-awareness-per-monitor-v2/43537991#43537991), they looks same problem as your description.

Comment: Bounty expires tomorrow; If Reza or CoCalceDew wants to post a question, I'll award it the bounty.