# Calling a program in C# Program using VisualStudio

Tags: c#, .net, svg, cmd, converters

I made a CMD program that can convert the photos from Png to SVG format.
how can I call this program in a C# program?

the Photo Path is:

```
    `var path = @"C:\Users\";

    var sourcePath = Path.Combine(path, @"emoji1.png");

    var destPath = Path.Combine(path, @"png01.svg");`
```

i would like to open my cmd Photo converter Program in other C# Program`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arguments = ""; //optional, if your cmd converter can accept path to photo as an argument - you can put it here
var proc = Process.Start("path to executable", arguments);
proc.WaitForExit();// if you need to work in sync with that app
```