# Start Blazor server app to use it in End-to-End tests (Selenium)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, blazor-server-side

I am new with Blazor and have to test the Blazor server app (`.Net7`).
Address: `http://localhost:5000`

My test (NUnit / Specflow) is working if I start the app in the background.

Now I want to start the Blazor app in the BeforeScenario.
I tried to get it working with WebApplicationFactory<> but failed.

I assume I just need to start a server because Selenium is starting the client by itself.

Can me someone explain the concept and provide a minimal solution. I think it will be easier to extend it later them start with all options.

Thanks
Nico

Comment: Will it work if you start a process? See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/181719/486564 In your case, you should go for `dotnet run`.